# Show / Hide child DIVs on click on the main DIV, similar to spoiler (pure JS)

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have 20 rows of DIVs. The initial state hides all spoilers and is like below (I show the first 3 rows here):

```
<div class="main" onClick="showHide()">
some text 1
<div class="spoiler hide">spoiler</div>
</div>

<div class="main" onClick="showHide()">
some text 2
<div class="spoiler hide">spoiler 2</div>
</div>

<div class="main" onClick="showHide()">
some text 3
<div class="spoiler hide">spoiler 3</div>
</div>
```

etc..

CSS:

```
<style>
.main{background:silver;padding:1em;margin-bottom:1em}
.hide{display:none}
.show{display:block}
</style>
```

My goal is to manipulate/change the spoiler classes after user clicks on the "main" DIV. That is, after clicking on one of the "main" DIVs the "spoiler hide" class should automatically change to "spoiler show" so that the text is shown. And when user clicks on another "main" DIV, all 'spoiler show' classes should change to 'spoiler hide' and only the currently clicked "main" DIV should apply the 'spoiler show' class.

So it's basically like a toggle where only one (the last clicked) DIV shows the spoiler. I hope to find the simplest/fastest solution (JS in one line would work too).

I tried to use some JS function like below, but cannot make it work. I also read that 'document.querySelectorAll' might be used somehow.. I cannot use jQuery here.

```
<script>
function showHide() {
var e = document.getElementsByClassName('spoiler hide');
for(i=0; i<e.length; i++) {
e[i].className ='spoiler show';
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
    function showHide(sender) {    
    var e = sender.getElementsByClassName('spoiler hide');

    for(i=0; i<e.length; i++) 
    {
        e[i].className ='spoiler show';
    }
}
</script>    

<div class="main" onclick="showHide(this)">
    some text 1
    <div class="spoiler hide">spoiler</div>
</div>

<div class="main" onClick="showHide(this)">
    some text 2
    <div class="spoiler hide">spoiler 2</div>
</div>

<div class="main" onClick="showHide(this)">
    some text 3
    <div class="spoiler hide">spoiler 3</div>
</div>
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/t0shq84f/

Comment: It works but not exactly the way I need - ie. it should show only one spoiler at a time (and on click it should hide all other spoilers)..

Comment: Thank you - it is more complicated than I thought but it works.. so it cannot be done a simpler way? (if not, this is good solution too..)

Comment: Of course there's a simpler way, it can be done with no javascript with http://jsfiddle.net/arg3jsut/

Comment: Great.. I get the idea even though the JS solution works better, ie. the divs show/hide correctly. With CSS not sure if it's possible to get the same consistent effect..